# Are questions calling for speculation on current or future events on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This Question - [What can the rest of the World do to stop Israel-Palestine war?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/what-can-the-rest-of-the-world-do-to-stop-israel-palestine-war) - does not have a real answer.

It is calling for speculation about what we could do to solve the problem.  Of course as with most conflicts there are at least 2 different sides and the definition of resolve is completely different depending on what side you are on.  On top of that there are probably hundreds of potential solutions that could end it.

I think a question asking what plans have been proposed that have a potential for being found acceptable by both sides would definitely be on topic.  There have been in the past questions that have asked about possible future events and what might be done.  Again asking for proposals that have been put forth as a way to deal with these problems is probably on topic, but asking for original ideas on how to solve the problem seems like our version of the [Gorilla vs Shark Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

So should these types of questions be considered on topic?

Comment: Sam already closed it, and I can't say I disagree with his decision. The question was interesting, but we clearly failed in supporting it (the answers aren't stellar, tons of back & forth discussions in comments). If this is how speculative questions end up, then I don't see any reason to allow them on the site.

Answer (score 4):

Speculative questions are bad because they're either **Too Broad**, **Primarily opinion based**, or both.

If you want to close a speculative question, just pick which of those two close reasons you think applies the most.

If neither of those 2 close reasons apply, then I'd suggest that you reconsider why you think that question really needs to be closed.

Comment: I am not really sure that the question here is too broad or opinion based.  There are a few solutions that the world could take that are consise and factual... granted the easiest answer is genocide(not what I would suggest as an actual solution just a potential solution).  But lets face it there are several tried and true solutions that would stop this for both sides.  There is just no will to enact them.

Comment: @Chad, indeed. The Nazis didn't call it a final solution for nothing.

Comment: @user1873 - I actually meant outside peacekeeping forces and active policing and foriegn investment.  When rich people start spending lots of money the stupid crap stops.